# How do I make an Internet Explorer add-on that doesn't display a toolbar?

Tags: delphi, internet-explorer, bho

I'm trying to make an IE add-on that works only in background, without a toolbar panel. I do not want my add-on to display a toolbar panel because i do not need it. I found an example add-on in Delphi, but how do I make it to work in the background without a toolbar?

Comment: That download URL does not work.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Please check the updated link. I have found Your name in many useful posts about programming, maybe you can help me to learn IE addon with delphi. I need a simple addon which will inject javascript code when page load is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example project you provide implements a [Tool Band](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144099.aspx). It implements the `IDeskBand` interface to display a toolbar in IE.

For the functionality you are asking for, you need to implement a [Browser Helper Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250436.aspx) instead, which is a completely different beast, and a very different implementation than a Tool Band.